# Can Droidekas speak?

Tags: star-wars, droids

I'm curious about whether or how Droidekas can communicate with other droids, since they seem to be the only type of Separatist droid in the films to never be shown to say anything. Even Vulture droids and Buzz droids make chattering noises in *Revenge of the Sith*, while Droidekas are the only unit that isn't even able to issue commands for gameplay purposes in some of the games, such as *Battlefront* (2004).

**Have Droidekas ever been shown to speak or otherwise communicate, either aloud or by radio?** Canon and Legends sources are preferred, but officially licensed non-canon works are also acceptable.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can hear them talking at 0:44. They appear to vocalise in Binary.

This ties in with their profile in the [RPG core rulebook](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Roleplaying_Game_Saga_Edition_Core_Rulebook). They can understand Basic and speak Binary.

[image]